# proving:$f(x)-f(x^{*})\geq\frac{1}{2m}\left|\left|\nabla f(x)\right|\right|_{2}^{2}$

Tags: calculus, optimization, taylor-expansion, convex-optimization, gradient-descent

let there be a strongly convex function $f(x)$.

I want to prove that if: $\forall x\in Dom(f):mI\succcurlyeq\nabla^{2}f(x)$
then:

$f(x)-f(x^{*})\geq\frac{1}{2m}\left|\left|\nabla f(x)\right|\right|_{2}^{2}$

where $ \succcurlyeq\ $is the positive semi-definite notation.

NOTE: $x^{*}$ is the optimum point of $f(x)$ , in this case it's
the minimum point

My Solution:

for some $\ z\in Dom(f):mI\succcurlyeq\nabla^{2}f(z)$, then:

$mI\succcurlyeq\nabla^{2}f(z)$ is equivalent to $\rightarrow\nabla^{2}f(z)-mI\preccurlyeq0$
which means that $\forall x,y,z:$

$(x-y)^{T}(\nabla^{2}f(z)-mI)(x-y)\leq0$$\rightarrow(x-y)^{T}(\nabla^{2}f(z))(x-y)-(x-y)^{T}(mI)(x-y)\leq0$

which leads to: $(x-y)^{T}(\nabla^{2}f(z))(x-y)\leq m(x-y)^{T}(I)(x-y)=m\Vert x-y\parallel^{2}$

$(x-y)^{T}(\nabla^{2}f(z))(x-y)\leq m\Vert x-y\parallel^{2}$

from taylor's expansion:

$f(y)=f(x)+\nabla f(x)^{T}(y-x)+\frac{1}{2}(y-x)^{T}\nabla^{2}f(z)(y-x)$

taking: $y=x^{*}$:

$f(x^{*})=f(x)+\nabla f(x)^{T}(x^{*}-x)+\frac{1}{2}(y-x)^{T}\nabla^{2}f(z)(x^{*}-x)$

$\Rightarrow f(x^{*})-f(x)\leq$ $\nabla f(x)^{T}(x^{*}-x)+\frac{1}{2}m\Vert x-x^{*}\parallel^{2}$

$\Rightarrow f(x)-f(x^{*})\geq$ $\nabla f(x)^{T}(x-x^{*})-\frac{1}{2}m\Vert x-x^{*}\parallel^{2}$

we define: $x-x^{*}=t$

$\Rightarrow f(x)-f(x^{*})\geq$ $\underset{g(t)}{\underbrace{\overset{g_{1}(t)}{\overbrace{\nabla f(x)^{T}(t)}}-\frac{1}{2}m\Vert t\parallel^{2}}}$

$\Rightarrow dg_{1}=\nabla f(x)^{T}dt$ $\rightarrow\nabla g_{1}(t)=\nabla f(x)$

$\Rightarrow$$\nabla g(t)=0\rightarrow$$\nabla f(x)-\frac{1}{2}m\cdot2t=0\rightarrow t^{*}=\frac{\nabla f(x)}{m}$

$min\{g(t)\}=g(t^{*})=$$\nabla f(x)^{T}\left(\frac{\nabla f(x)}{m}\right)-\frac{1}{2}m\left|\left|\frac{\nabla f(x)}{m}\right|\right|^{2}$=$\frac{1}{2m}\left|\left|\nabla f(x)\right|\right|_{2}^{2}$

since $f(x)-f(x^{*})\geq$ $\underset{g(t)}{\underbrace{\overset{g_{1}(t)}{\overbrace{\nabla f(x)^{T}(t)}}-\frac{1}{2}m\Vert t\parallel^{2}}}$
holds for every $t$ then, (which is equivalent to every $x$)

$\underset{x}{min}\{f(x)-f(x^{*})\}$ $\geq$$\underset{\text{min\{g(t)\}}}{\underbrace{\frac{1}{2m}\left|\left|\nabla f(x)\right|\right|_{2}^{2}}}$ for
every x.

$\Rightarrow$$f(x)-f(x^{*})$ $\geq$$\frac{1}{2m}\left|\left|\nabla f(x)\right|\right|_{2}^{2}$

My problem is with the step: $\Rightarrow$$\nabla g(t)=0\rightarrow$$\nabla f(x)-\frac{1}{2}m\cdot2t=0\rightarrow t^{*}=\frac{\nabla f(x)}{m}$

since $x-x^{*}=t$, and by taking the gradient with respect to $t$
, I can't assume that $\nabla f(x)$ is constant, because $x$ and $t$ are dependant.

how can I make this solution right?

Comment: What is $mI\succcurlyeq\nabla^{2}f(z)$$\rightarrow\nabla^{2}f(z)-mI\preccurlyeq0$?

Comment: @xpaul if you are asking about the notation, then its the positive semi-definite notation.

Comment: You have two $mI$s.

Comment: by the $\rightarrow$ I meant that the two expressions are equivalent. is it clear now ?

Comment: You edited? Now it is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use Taylor's expansion, moreover as you have just expanded till the quadratic term. Your proof only holds for a quadratic function. The result to be proved is incorrect. Consider the following one-dimensional function, $f$:
$$\
f: [-3, +\infty] \to {R} \ \text{ where } \ f(x)=-x^3-3x^2
$$
You can check that $x^*=-2$ is local minimum. $f''(x) \leq 12$ for all $x$ in domain of $f$. Your result tells the following:
$$\
f(x)-f(-2)\geq\frac{1}{24}(f'(x))^2\geq0
$$
Obviously, this is not true for $x>1$.

The result you want holds if $f$ is convex. We can show that $\|\nabla^2 f(x)\|\leq m$ and hence, $f$ is $m$-smooth.  Following is the proof:

Let $z=x-\frac{1}{m}\left(\nabla f(x)\right)$,
\begin{align}
f(x^*)-f(x)
&= f(x^*)-f(z)+f(z)-f(x)\\
&\leq f(z) -f(x) \qquad \qquad \qquad \quad \qquad \text{[From Convexity]}\\
&\leq\nabla f(x)^T\left(z-x\right)+\frac{m}{2}\|z-x\|^2 \quad \text{[From Smoothness]}\\
&\leq -\frac{1}{m}\|\nabla f(x)\|^2+\frac{1}{2m}\|\nabla f(x)\|^2\\
&\leq -\frac{1}{2m}\|\nabla f(x)\|^2
\end{align}
Hence, we prove the required result.

**Note:** $\|.\|$ is spectral norm and $l_2$ norm for matrices and vectors respectively.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. I already knew this, I was asking for an alternative way for the proof.

Comment: @FirasAliAbdelGhani Hope this alternate proof helps.

Comment: thanks for for answer Shiv, the Convexity step you did is unclear. where did $f(x^*)$ go?

Comment: Since $x^*$ is the minimum and $f$ is convex. We can say $f(x^*)\leq f(z)$. Hence, that term becomes negative and we can bound it by zero.

Comment: Okay, Looks legit to me. just one last thing, if $f(x) $  is strongly convex then there should be strict inequality " $ \leq $ " . right?

Comment: Interesting! I guess you are correct that will bring strong inequality in the result too.

Comment: @ShivTavker could you please take a look of this and help me with the solution? Suppose that $x^*$ is an optimal solution to the following least squares problem:
$$ \min_{x\in R^n} f(x): = \frac{1}{2} \| Ax - b \|_2^2.$$ 
Clearly, we have $f(x) \ge f(x^*) \ \forall x \in R^n.$ Prove that the difference $[f(x) - f(x^*)]$ between the objective function values of any feasible solution and optimal solution is the following: 
$$ f(x) - f(x^*) = \frac{1}{2} \| Ax - Ax^*\|^2_2, \ \forall \ x \in R^n.$$

Comment: @holala can you please post it as new question and mention this question as a reference? I will be more than happy to answer it. Do put the question link here.

Comment: @ShivTavker https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3932996/difference-between-objective-function-values-of-any-feasible-solution-and-optima