# Proof that strong convexity implies Polyak-Lojasiewicz inequality is satisfied

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I am attempting to find a proof of strong-convexity implying the Polyak- Lojasiewicz (PL) inequality is satisfied. As I understand it, strong convexity means that:
$$ \textbf{H} f \succcurlyeq \mu I$$
for some $\mu>0$, where $\textbf{H}f$ is the Hessian matrix of $f$ and $I$ is the identity matrix.

The PL inequality states that:

$$\frac{1}{2}\|\nabla f(x)\|^2 \geq \mu(f(x) - f(x^*))$$

where $x^*$ is the value of $x$ for which $f(x)$ is minimized.

This paper http://www.optimization-online.org/DB_FILE/2016/08/5590.pdf states that if a function is strongly convex with constant $\mu$, then it must satisfy the PL inequality with the same constant (page 4, section 2.3, first sentence).

I found a source that says this can be done by minimizing the following inequality:

$$f(y)\ge f(x)+\nabla f(x)^T(y-x)+\frac{\mu}{2}\lVert y-x \rVert^2 \tag{1}$$

in terms of $y$ to get $$f(x^*) \ge f(x)-\frac{1}{2\mu}\|\nabla f(x)\|^2.$$

I don't understand this. How exactly is the inequality being minimized in terms of $y$ here? How do I go from strong convexity to equation (1) to this result?

Comment: A lot of books actually use (1) as the definition of strong convexity, since it does not require $f$ to be twice differentiable. The two notions are equivalent for functions whose Hessian is well-defined. A hint to get from (1) to your desired inequality: $x^*$ minimizes a convex function $f$ if and only if $\nabla f(x^*)=0$.

Comment: Thank you @Zim! I understand how to get (1) now. I am still a little confused about reaching the inequality. How would $\nabla f(x^*) = 0$ fit into the equation? Am I allowed to substitute in $x = x^*$ (in addition to $y = x^*$)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Wow, this was a very confusing statement they gave there, but eventually I was able to get to it. Since $f$ is $\mu$-strongly convex, then we have $$f(y)\geq f(x)+\nabla f(x)^T(y-x)+\frac{\mu}{2}\|y-x\|^2$$
Now, minimize the inequity with respect to $y$. Minimization maintains the inequality relation, therefore we will focus on each side separately. LHS is straightforward and we have:
$$\min_y \{f(y)\} = f(x^*)$$
To solve the RHS we will differentiate with respect to $y$ to obtain
$$\frac{\partial RHS}{\partial y}=\nabla f(x)+\mu(y-x)=0\iff y=x-\frac{1}{\mu}\nabla f(x)$$
Plug back the optimal $y$ we found to the RHS and we get $$f(x)-\frac{1}{\mu}\|\nabla f(x)\|^2 + \frac{1}{2\mu}\|\nabla f(x)\|^2$$ and overall we have
$$f(x^*)\geq f(x)-\frac{1}{2\mu}\|\nabla f(x)\|^2$$

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much, your answer clarifies a lot of things. Just one question, I just wanted to check how you got the $-\nabla f(x) $ term in your derivative. Should it not be positive? I tried it myself and I got the same end result with a positive sign on this term. Could be an error on my part, so I just wanted to clarify? Thank you so much for your response!

Comment: @Aryan you're absolutely right, it's a typo. I edited the answer

Comment: You also need to show that $f(x)$is convex or it may not be a global minimum. But by computing the Hessian, it is immediate.